# Choose table in DB based on object field

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a question about Hibernate. I have object that must be reflected in DB. It contains one field 'platform' - enum FACEBBOK, TWITTER etc. And in my DB I have appropriate tables: object_facebook, object_twitter etc. My question is: how to setup Hibernate to insert row in appropriate table?

```
// what is needed in @Table annotation?
public class MyObject {
   // some fields
   // 
   private Platorm platform;
}
```

Objects with Facebook platform must be in 'object_facebook' and with Twitter in 'object_twitter'. I can't store all rows in one table, because it will be very big amount of rows.

Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should read about use inheritance strategy `Table Per Class`- It is only tip.